# Vim Visual Mode Is Behaving Strangely In cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

I have recently started my first job in a windows shop in over a decade, so have set up cygwin so I can continue using tmux + vim, as I have become accustomed to over the years. Everything is working great so far, except that in vim, my visual mode is deleting the character after the selection if I highlight something and then hit d.

For example:

If the line is:
`Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'`

I press v to get into visual mode and then select the text between the two single quotes (represented by brackets):
`Plug '[tpope/vim-sensible]'`

And then I hit d to delete. The expected result is:
`Plug ''`

But what I get is:
`Plug '`

If I highlight the beginning single quote as well:
`Plug ['tpope/vim-sensible]'`

Then when I delete the expected result is:
`Plug '`

But what I actually get is:
`Plug`

Does anybody know what might be going on to cause this? My .vimrc is identical to my linux machines, none of which have this problem.

Comment: Change cursor shape to "block"

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt pointed out above, this can be fixed by changing cursor shape to "block" in the Options->Looks->Cursor section of the cygwin terminal app.